# ASP.NET intranet web site writing text files to a network folder

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, permissions

I have an intranet application that needs to write a text file. That text file needs to live on a network share folder. I am accessing it via the UNC name "\\fileserver\subfolder\TEST.txt" and am of course running into the dreaded "Access to path denied" error.

My intranet web site is running on IIS 6. I have another application on the intranet that needs to be able to access the logged on user's account using Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"]. I have found that this will not work if I enable anonymous access to the site. I'm using integrated Windows authentication. What can I do to enable write access to my network share folder for the web application? I'm thinking I can't use impersonation without breaking my other app. Can I do something to just this portion (folder) of my site that won't effect my other app?

I'll need step by step what to do in IIS and/or on the folder settings for the network folder I'm trying to write to to get this to work.

Comment: In iis, create a virtual folder pointing to the network share and use different credentials for logging in. Then let your application read/write to that folder, which it will think is local to it.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a bit of a hack would be to impersonate the part of the code that writes to the file. I.e. you switch to a user that has enough permissions to write to the file.

There is a small [`Impersonator` helper class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User) that you can use to do this like e.g.:

```
... 
using ( new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword" ) )
{
   ...

   <code that executes under the new context>

   ...
}

...
```

The drawback of this approach is that you somewhere have to store the username and password, either hardcoded in your code or inside e.g. your web.config file. Both things could be bad from a security point-of-view.

Comment: Thank you Uwe Keim. This got me started down the right path.

I tried using code like this around my file write: